# Is there any possibility to do automatic update in the background in iOS every minute?

Tags: ios, swift, background

Is there any possibility to run a task (receive JSON from web and parse it) in iOS when the App is not running in background? I already had a look at the background fetch, but couldn't figure out if it is possible to run it in a defined period (it seems that it is running randomly).

I would need a process to fetch some data every minute for a specified time - e.g. after setting a timer, get data from web every 1 minute till you reach a goal - for max. 30 minutes or so.

Does anybody has an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend background tasks for about 10 minutes application.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler() method.

In case you are fetching data from web, you can use apple push notification service and set content-available property to download/fetch contents from web in background

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This 10 minute time would be better than nothing...setting up a push server for this is not really possible. Do you know if i can run a background fetch once at a specific time? I know I can do this when setting region based alerts, but is it also possible time-based?

Comment: there is no way to schedule a fetch. I suggest using https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp github project to setup your server and push notification in a timely manner to specific device.